# MsysGit Configuration steps issues

Tags: git

Please help me to fix the git configuration steps.

I am not able to connect to remote git repository,I have got error each time when I tries to connect to remote bare git repository **"does not appear to be a git repository" and "could not read from the remote repository"**

**Following are my configuration steps:-**

Pre-setup

1. Download Cygwin
2. Download msysgit
3. Download TortiseGIT
4. Download PuTTY Installer

**Step 1 – Cygwing Configuration**

```
Host Configuration of SSH
```

1. Run cygwin in Administrator mode
2. mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd
3. mkgroup  -l > /etc/group
4. Add System Environment Variable 
   Variable=> Path => C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\bin and C:\DevTools\cygwin64\bin
5. If sshd service is running then stop it => net stop sshd
6. ssh-host-config
   You’ll see the script generate some default files, and then you’ll be prompted for whether or not you want to enable “Privilege Separation.” It’s on by default in standard installations of OpenSSH on other systems, so go ahead and say “yes” to the prompt.
7. net start sshd
8. Exit From window

   **User Configuration of SSH**
9. Run cygwin without administrator, simply double click on it.
10. ssh-user-config
11. You’ll be asked to create specific keys for your user account, type “yes” to the SSH2 RSA & remainig other keys to "no".
12. That’s it! You’re all configured. If you want to test your configuration 
    ssh –v localhost
13. Create a file "authorized_keys" in C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\home\GauravA.ssh\ and paste the public key file "id_rsa.pub" data  into it in a single row and save it.

    **Accessing from local system to server**
14. Install Putty on local system
15. Copy the id_rsa file to local machine.
16. Run puttygen and load this key and save as .ppk.
17. Add private key .ppk in pageant.
18. Run Putty with port 22.

6.Prompt for username & password.

**Step 2 – Configuring msysgit.**

1.Once it’s installed – you now have 2 windows which I will name 
    1. Git Bash (Right Click Mouse on a file/folder in Explorer) and 
    2. Start –> Programs –> cygwinSSH –> Start a Unix Bash Shell – Unix Bash.

1. Finally, goto your Git-Core folder in the GIT installed directory -C:\DevTools\Git\libexec\git-core – and copy the files => git.exe, git-receive-pack.exe, git-upload-archive.exe and git-upload-pack.exe and paste these into your C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\bin\
   And copy one more file C:\DevTools\Git\bin\libiconv-2.dll and paste into your C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\bin\
2. Modify the User Environment

   1. The problem with SSH is that it sets its $HOME environment to the c:\users\ 
      or c:\Documents and Settings\ variable – and GIT looks for authorized_keys in this    folder. Of course, we don’t want this we setup our Server Environment in the    C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\Home\.ssh and so we want GIT to look for keys in there.
   2. Open Windows Explorer – go into C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\Home\\ and open    the .bashrc file using a text editor (Aside: Be sure not to attempt to format 
      this file as it has Unix Encodings NOT Dos encodings – i.e. just open it in a text editor and   don’t use another viewer unless you want encoding errors – you don’t need to read the text  in this file if you are following these instructions to a tee.)
   3. Put the Cursor at the beginning of the .bashrc file and use CTRL+F to find the following     text - bashrc file.

   4.After the text .bashrc file# (after the pound with a space) – paste in -
   export HOME=/c/DevTools/cygwin64/home/.
3. Ensure there is a “space” before and after this paste in – i.e. .bashrc file#export 
   HOME=/c/DevTools/cygwin64/home/

   1. Save this file and close it.
   2. Copy this file and navigate to your windows assigned home directory (Aside: GIT will     still be looking for your path in this directory so we need to set to refer to our  C:\DevTools\cygwin\root\home\\directory instead)
   3. Paste this in your c:\users\ or c:\Documents and Settings\ – so 
      it now has c:\users\.bashrc for example.
   4. Open both a Git Bash and a Unix Bash Shell – Unix    Bash shell
   5. Type echo $HOME – into both – they should both spit out – /home/
   6. If one does not – you need to set it via cmd- 
      export  HOME=/c/DevTools/cygwin64/home/
   7. Set Following sytem Environment Variable =>

      1. CYGWIN_HOME =C:\DevTools\cygwin64\
      2. GIT_SSH=C:\DevTools\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe
      3. Path=C:%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin
         C:\DevTools\Git\cmd
         C:\DevTools\TortoiseGit\bin
         C:\DevTools\Git\bin
      4. SVN_SSH=C:\DevTools\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe

**Step 3 – Using GIT and Plink**

1. Navigate to D:\ and create a new directory called Git_Repository.git
2. Select Git Bash
3. goto folder D:\Git_repository.git and execute cmd=> git --bare init
4. You’ll now see a (BARE: master) appear and can close the window.
5. Now it’s time to clone this repository to our local development environment and finally start using GIT
6. Navigate to where you want to have your local repository – in my case D:\SCM_REPO\
7. Right click inside this Directory and hit Git Clone
8. Enter your URL as ssh://GauravA@192.168.248.58:22/d/Git_repository.git 
   There is no need to Load Putty Key as we have already done this using pageant. Hit OK
   and got following Error

!Error Message

Comment: Has `git --bare init` actually worked? ie: is there a `.git`directory inside `Git_Repository.git`? If yes, can you clone it elsewhere on the same computer?

Comment: No there is no .git directory in it.

Comment: I made a mistake: since it's `bare`, it's normal that there isn't a `.git` in it. To check if the repo has been correctly initialized you can try to run `git status`. If it says ` Not a git repository` there's an issue at step 3.4. If it says `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree` then we're good so far. Next step would be to try to clone on the same computer.

Comment: git status gives same error as you said "Fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree"

Comment: So you actually have a git repo. Good. Now, can you clone it? For example create a directory D:\test, and "Right click inside this Directory and hit Git Clone". The clone url should simply be `..\Git_repository.git`. If it works, it means your issue comes from the url `ssh://GauravA@192.168.248.58:22/d/Git_repository.git`. Then my  biggest suspect would be the port, and I would suggest you try to clone from `ssh://GauravA@192.168.248.58/d/Git_repository.git`

Comment: both the url gives same error

Cloning into 'Git_Remote_repo'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: If even on the same computer you can't clone, no need to try with ssh yet. You could try in command line, with "Git bash". From the start, you could do `mkdir repo1; cd repo1; git --bare init; cd ..; mkdir repo2; cd repo2; git clone ../repo1`. Does it work?

Comment: Yes it worked,

$ git clone ../repo1
Cloning into 'repo1'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

Comment: Nice. I don't know what's wrong with this GUI, but at least we're able to clone. Last step, since it's what you wanted to do: try to clone over ssh: `git clone ssh://GauravA@192.168.248.58/path/to/repo1`

Comment: I have been working on this issues since 20+ days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it!

Using the URL:

```
git push GauravA@192.168.248.58:D:/Git_repo.git
```

There is no need to use `ssh://` at start of URL and port Number after IP address